# Parrot OS virtualbox is connected to wifi but websites don't load

Tags: wifi, virtualbox, parrotsec

my Parrot OS says its connected to wifi but when I open firefox and try to enter websites like Facebook or Youtube it won't load them at all.

I've tried sudo apt install wireless-tools and reinstall wireless-tools and its says everything is installed up and running but still no websites will load. Anyone know how to fix this?

I'm running Parrot Security VM on Virtualbox 6.1.10 and my wifi adapter is a TP Link TL-WN722N v2

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the anonsurf option.